# Why does youtube video work everywhere but other video sources no?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

So this will sound like a stupid question, but I notice that video from youtube works on pretty much all browsers without any setup work. However, use a security DVR or a IP camera, and suddenly you need a custom applet that is OS specific added to run it. Why does youtube just work everywhere? Because all the browser makers set it up by default? If the youtube video presentation method is so universal, why does not every video device use the same method/plugin as youtube?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube doesn't "just" work everywhere. They have hundreds of engineers working to keep it working everywhere. They have several copies of each video that work on a sub set of platforms, and spend a lot of time making sure each platform works and continues to work.

Comment: Thanks! So again, why did not everyone use whatever method youtube uses as well? Why isn't that the standard?

Comment: So your question is Why doesn't every company hire hundreds of engineers?